# Web Bluetooth send text from web browser to android wear OS watch

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, notifications, sendmessage, web-bluetooth

I want to send text message or notification from my web browser to android watch using web BT API.
Is this possible?
This is the code for requesting device. I choose device from UI and pair. But, console.log return empty.

```
var device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
    acceptAllDevices: true,
    optionalServices: [ CHARACTERISTIC_TX ] // TODO
});
 
console.log("device = "+JSON.stringify(device))
```

I just want to send message from my web page button onclick action and get message from android device. Is there any other ways to connect android device and web page by using bluetooth in JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think this is possible because wearOS doesn't support connections to arbitrary Bluetooth devices. But, the wearOS device is presumably connected to an Android device and Android apps can expose custom GATT services. Perhaps you can have the page connect to the Android app and forward the info to the wearOS app?